# How to change keyboard layout using Left Alt?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

In Ubuntu 12.04, I used to changed keyboard layout just by pressing Left Alt. After upgrading to 14.04, it is not possible anymore.

It is very annoying, to the extent that I'm tempted to downgrade Ubuntu because I need to switch layout frequently and not comfortable with any combination. So I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file `/etc/default/keyboard`. You should see there a line that starts with `XKBOPTIONS` word, for reference here's mine:

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:rctrl_rshift_toggle,grp_led:scroll,lv3:ralt_switch,compose:rwin"
```

Inside the quotes is a list of options separated by comma. Layout switching option looks like *grp:the_key_you_want*, list of options is described in *[man xkeyboard-config](http://linux.die.net/man/7/xkeyboard-config)*. To make layout switching with the <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> just add the option *(or change if you have one)* `grp:lalt_toggle`. E.g. with my config:

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:lalt_toggle,grp_led:scroll,lv3:ralt_switch,compose:rwin"
```

Then just reboot *(perhaps log-out would be enough, but I am not sure)*.

But I actually think that somewhere in graphical keyboard configuration you should find a way to change the key. I am using AwesomeWM in Kubuntu, so I can't provide the exact way, but I encourage you to search it.

**UPD:** from the discussion with the author it was found that `/etc/default/keyboard` file doesn't work the way it should. It seems that something overrides its settings for the XServer start.

As a workaround it is possible to add at the start up a script with the command `setxkbmap -layout gb,af -option grp:lalt_toggle,grp_led:scroll`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm using gnom-fallback and I see that `XKBOPTIONS=""` despite the fact that I'm alrady using a combo key to switch layout. Are you sure that this works for gnome too?

Comment: @Paulrx well, at least from all the time I'm using *buntu, I don't remember when it didn't work. But tell me then one thing: what's the content of the `XKBLAYOUT` in your file?

Comment: `XKBLAYOUT="gb"`

Comment: @Paulrx okay, run then the command `setxkbmap -option grp:lalt_toggle,grp_led:scroll`, and tell if layout change now works?

Comment: Just tried `XKBOPTIONS="grp:lalt_toggle"`. It has no effect after reboot.

Comment: @Paulrx okay, what's the second language you're using?

Comment: @Paulrx nice, so, I suppose it is Persian — in the config it is being declared as `af`. Then change the `XKBLAYOUT="gb"` → `XKBLAYOUT="gb,af"`. Also, you can test it without reboot, with `setxkbmap -layout gb,af -option grp:lalt_toggle,grp_led:scroll`, it should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29637/discussion-between-paulrx-and-hi-angel).

Comment: See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322 --- still mostly unfixed.